# Issue/ bug in Google Drive Dr. Edit

Tags: google-drive-api

We are currently trying Dr. Edit application of Google Drive application in Java.

With Dr.Edit, we are able to login, do the Handshake with Google Drive, and also open Dr.Edit, but getting following exception while accessing Drive Service, and don't know whether there is bug or it is an implementation issue. I have also attached the errors as an attachment. Is it because we are not accessing correct version ?

```
![Google Drive Exception][1]
Error Snippet
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing/svc Reason:

    Could not initialize class com.google.api. services.drive.Drive

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.services.drive.Drive
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder.build (Drive.java:8241)
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.DrEditServlet.getDriveService (DrEditServlet.java:222)
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.FileServlet.doGet (FileServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)........
```

Little guidance from any one ,or even if we are pointed to right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: `war / WEB-INF / lib / google-api-services-drive-v2-rev70-1.14.1-beta.jar` should contain the class. Is it there?

Answer (score 1):

Your project doesn't contain Drive API jar, download it and all of its dependencies from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API